# Converting Baidu coordinates to WGS 1984 Web Mercator Auxiliary Sphere

Tags: python, pyproj

I'm trying to convert Baidu coordinates to WGS 1984 Web Mercator Auxiliary Sphere. I have a csv file in which each observation has the latitude and longitude for 2 separate points (4 columns total). I want to eventually import the csv file into Arcmap so that I can create point shapefiles(one for the start point and another one for the end point for each observation).

I have tried to convert the coordinates using Python code with no luck. How can I successfully convert them?

```
# Load the data from the CSV file
data = pd.read_csv('ming.csv')

transformer = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(baidu, wgs84)


# Define the function for converting coordinates
def convert_coordinates(x, y):
    # Convert the coordinates from Baidu to WGS 1984 Web Mercator Auxiliary Sphere
    lon, lat = transform(baidu, wgs84, x, y)

    # Return the converted coordinates
    return lat, lon

# Apply the function to the "Start.X", "Start.Y", "End.X", and "End.Y" columns
data[['Start.X', 'Start.Y']] = data.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(convert_coordinates(row['Start.X'], row['Start.Y'])), axis=1)
data[['End.X', 'End.Y']] = data.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(convert_coordinates(row['End.X'], row['End.Y'])), axis=1)

# Save the updated data to a new CSV file
data.to_csv('ming_converted.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: What Python code?  What went wrong?  Please update your question to include this extra information.

Comment: You have a tag for ArcMap and mention it in your title.  However, your question body makes no mention of how ArcMap is relevant to your question so I'm replacing the tag with pyproj (which is in your code) and removing ArcMap from your title.

Comment: @polygeo it is to eventually import the csv file into Arcmap so that I can create point shapefiles (one for the start point and another one for the end point for each observation)

Comment: You only need ArcPy to do the Excel to Table, Make XY Layer, Export Features then Project.

Comment: @PolyGeo thank you. Why won't my coordinates transform from Baidu to the WGS 1984 Web Mercator Auxiliary Sphere coordinates with my code above though?

Comment: That’s a pyproj question and I do not code with that.